# How to get files path to table java

Tags: java

I have a little problem getting the list of files in my table. Here is my `listFilesForFolder` method:

```
class listFilesForFolder{

  public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
   String[ ] table = new String[5] ;

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            table[0] = fileEntry.getPath();
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getPath());
            System.out.println(table[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

giving me:

```
/home/piotr/Pobrane/162372-1.jpg
null
/home/piotr/Pobrane/skype-4.3.0.37-suse.i586.rpm
null
```

How can I fill my table with the Path of files?

Comment: You're not incrementing the array index. Am I missing something?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? why do you use a table, if you always use its first index?

Comment: sorry my bad I want to get all paths of files in folder and put them in table

Comment: why do you use the first index only? is there a reason? why do you use a table and not a list?

Comment: that's not a table, that's an array. Every time you call the method you're creating a new array. There's a lot of work that has to be done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
fileEntry.isDirectory()
```

is returning `false` so it never satisfies the condition in

```
 if (fileEntry.isDirectory())
```

so no `table[0]` value is set.

get rid of the whole `if-else` block and replace it with just

```
table[0] = fileEntry.getPath();  // or whatever method you want to use to increment i
```

---

```
int i = 0;
for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
   table[i++] = fileEntry.getPath();
}
```

Comment: updated the answer. replace your `for` loop with what i put there.

Comment: I guess the if block is needed to recursively get the files of the subfolders.

Comment: he calls the method `listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);` in that if statement, which is what recursively checks folders for more files

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need a list, not an array. If you don't call the method recursively, then you will lose all the files of the subfolders. If you want to get the files of the subfolders, use something like that:

```
public List<String> listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

  for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        list.addAll(listFilesForFolder(fileEntry)); //recursively call the same method to get the files of the subfolder   
    } else {            
        list.add(fileEntry.getPath()); //add the files of this folder to the list
        System.out.println(fileEntry.getPath()); //prints only the files of all subfolders
    }        
  }
  return list; //returns all the files of this folder and all the files of its subfolders
}
```

If you require your final output to be an array and not a list, then just transform this list to an array, in the method from which you call `listFilesForFolder`, like that:

```
List<String> list = listFilesForFolder(intialFile);
String[] table = new String[list.size()];
table = list.toArray(table);  //the result as an array
```